# Removing dups FOR loop python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to write a function to remove duplicates in list using a for loop in python. This is what I've got:

```
[IN]:
L = [1, 1, "a", "b", 1, "a", "d"]
N = [ ]

def remove_dup(x):
    for x in range(len(L)):
        if L[x] not in N:
            N.append(x)
    return N
   
print(remove_dup(N))
```

My problem is instead of outputting [1, "a", "b", "d"] its returning this:

```
[OUT]:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Lol idk where there is coming from. At least its printing a list though.... Can someone help a girl out and tell me why I am getting a randomly generated list? I have tried switching out a bunch of variables when calling my function.

Thank you!

Comment: change `N.append(x)` to `N.append(L[x])`. `x` is index of the list `L` and `L[x]` is the element

Comment: Or use a `set` - `N = set(L)`.

Answer (score 2):

To `N`, you are appending `x` instead of `L[x]`.

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over the indices rather than the values, and then appending those to your new list. You need to either look up the element to add it, or just iterate over the values directly -- since you don't actually need the index for anything, this is going to be more convenient and readable code.

Separately, it's not a good idea to use a global list like that to return results, since it'll cause problems when you try to use your function more than once. Instead, create the "return" list inside your function. Also, you're not actually using the list passed in to the function (named `x`) -- you're just looking up values in the global `L` list instead. Which will also cause problems if you try to use your function with a different list.

So to fix all of those issues, and with variable names edited for readability:

```
# Iterating over indices
def remove_dups(in_list):
    result = []
    for index in range(len(in_list)):
        if in_list[index] not in result:
            result.append(in_list[index])
    return result

# Or over values (more readable):
def remove_dups(in_list):
    result = []
    for item in in_list:
        if item not in result:
            result.append(item)
    return result
```

Finally - using `in` on a list isn't the best way to check for duplicates, since it'll search the whole list every time. A much more convenient and performant way of doing this is to just convert it to a `set` and back:

```
def remove_dups(in_list):
    return list(set(in_list))
```

With the caveat that this will not keep the list elements in their original order.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `N.append(x)` use:

```
N.append(L[x])
```

In your case `x` is an index that goes from 0 to the size of `L` minus one. But you need the values that can be taken from `L` by index `x`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers about using `L[x]` as opposed to just `x` you could do something like this instead:

```
L = [1, 1, "a", "b", 1, "a", "d"]
N = [ ]

def remove_dup(x):
    for x in L:
        if x not in N:
            N.append(x)
    return N
   
print(remove_dup(N))
```

This way is slightly more readable in my opinion, instead of using indexes you're using the values. Either way works.

Comment: The use of parameters x, L, N is a bit confusing.

Comment: @ack, Agreed. Actually, x is immediately redefined as well, so tzaman's answer is probably best